# Change HTML code after page load (w/ jQuery ?)

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, replace

I'm trying to find out a way to modify the `HTML` code to **replace every Bootstrap col class name (col, col-xs-x, col-x etc.) by `col-12`** after the page is loaded.

I could do that with `.removeClass('name')` and then `.addClass('name')` but I need to use some RegEx because I want to modify Bootstrap `col` class names.

*From something like this :*

```html
<body>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-2"> Content 1 </div>
    <div class="col"> Content 2 </div>
</body>
```

*I want to modify to something like this :*

```html
<body>
    <div class="col-12"> Content 1 </div> <!--can even be class="col-12 col-12 col-12"-->
    <div class="col-12"> Content 2 </div>
</body>
```

I found here someone who did that with html().replace in jQuery so I tried to do the same but it doesn't work.

*Way like this:*

```js
$(document).ready(function () { // my RegEx works well, verified it on regex101
    let col_let_num = $('body').html().replace(/\bcol\b(\-[a-z]{0,2})?(\-)?([0-9]{0,2})?/i, 'col-12')
    $('body').html(col_let_num)
})
```

**So my question is, do you have any solution to change HTML content after the page is loaded ?**

Comment: I think you're not using bootstrap properly, if you use bootstrap breakpoint classes correctly you wouldn't need to remove them.

Comment: Adding bootstrap tag so bootstrap experts can chime in. I suggest explaining what is the problem and what you're trying to achieve instead of asking how to mass update HTML

Comment: Also `$('body').html()` is a terrible thing to do...

Comment: Yes but I can't find out a way to change these class name using RegEx. The fact is that if people check a box, I want the whole columns to be col-12. Is that clear?

Comment: Makes sense, I suggest adding this use case in the question, someone might have a clever answer using bootstrap utility classes

Comment: I think it is more clear now. :^)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add ')' to your Javascript.
but i really cant realize what you are trying to do here.
any way

```
$(document).ready(function () { // my RegEx works well, verified it on regex101
    let col_let_num = $('body').html().replace(/\bcol\b(\-[a-z]{0,2})?(\-)?([0-9]{0,2})?/i, 'col-12')
    $('body').html(col_let_num)
})
```

**Edited**
here you go

```
$('[class*="col"]').each((i, e) => {
    let classes = $(e).attr('class').split(/\s+/);

    classes.forEach(v => {
        let col_let_num = v.replace(/\bcol\b(\-[a-z]{0,2})?(\-)?([0-9]{0,2})?/i, 'col-12')
        $(e).attr('class', col_let_num)
    })
})
```

this should work.

Comment: Thanks, i added it. I want a way to replace every Bootstrap col class name by col-12.

Comment: @Kiji_T edited the answer with the correct way to do it. :)

Comment: It seems to work, but I have a doubt, I think it deleted me some <div>. Is it possible ?  (I'm looking at it)

Comment: @Kiji_T Hmm, nope. try to output the divs to see if there any changes before the code `console.log($('div').length)` and after.

Comment: Never mind, you're just a god. Thanks for this. I wonder why you add i, e and v in your function. Could you tell me why not using $(this) for example ?

Comment: @Kiji_t im using Arrow Functions which cannot be used with (This). Also .each parmas are (index, value/elment) while forEach params are (value/element, index)